# Laravel insert a bigint into mysql wrong

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, bigint

this is my table struct

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET time_zone = '+07:00';
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `merchants`;
CREATE TABLE `merchants` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`work_hour` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
* @property $name
* Class Merchant
* @package App
*/
class Merchant extends Model
{

/**
 * The table associated with the model
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = "merchants";

//
protected $fillable = [
    "name", "url", "address", "work_hour", "id"
];

public $incrementing = false;
}
```

echo PHP_INT_SIZE ;// 8
echo PHP_INT_MAX ; // 9223372036854775807

Everytime, I insert new record with ID is a bigint, It always wrong in DB

```
$merchant->id = $newId1;
$merchant->name = $request->name;
$merchant->url = $request->url;
$merchant->address = $request->address;
$merchant->work_hour = 'a';
$merchant->created_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$merchant->updated_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

$merchant->save();
```

$newId1 = 4550103638072627879; but it display in mysql -2144066090

Please help

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is NOT the variable type. It is the improper version of php extension of mysql.

Check your php version. If it is above 7.0, you should use mysqlnd driver extension other than others. mysqlnd driver will solve the big integer and many odd problems related to mysql. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store **bigints** as **string or float**, So try to insert your bingint value as string or else please change the data type to **varchar** from **bigint**

Comment: DB id field also is bigint.

Comment: Yes, If it is bigint you should store your value as string not an integer.

Comment: Why ? because PHP can handle this integer, mysql is also ok, why we need  change it to string ?

What happen with 'join' ?

Comment: In your below comment you have given $merchant->id = (string) $newId1; So what it does mean you have converted your $newId1 variable to string. Normally If the value is integer you no need to use quotes, normally bigint will not accept the values without quotes. So you need to insert bigint values as like string values with quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Change code

```
$merchant->id = (string) $newId1;
```

It worked well.

I dont know why :)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. I was already using the mysqlnd extension. Saving it as a string did the trick.